# Issue with ForEach working with imported .csv data

Tags: powershell

Import data from .csv and run ForEach not working due to being formatted odd in the ForEach loop

I've tried changing the .csv to include headers/no headers, I've tried a variation of foreach and foreach-object commands. If I display the variable that has the email address loaded it displays as I would expect.

So something along the lines of:

```
''' Import Data, in this instance a .csv with a single column of email addresses:
''' foreach line run the following command, the $line should represents each email address in the .csv
```

Code:

```
  $Accounts = Import-Csv C:\temp\Emails.csv

  ForEach ($line in $Accounts) {
      remove-msoluser -UserPrincipalName "$line" -Force  
  }
```

All I'm trying to do is import a .csv with a single column of email address and for each email address in there I need to run a single liner PS command for Azure purpose.

The issue is when the foreach loop runs, it seems to retain the 1st line and add each subsequent line onto it, resulting in none being successful.

So the returned error in my case is:

> User Not Found.  User: @{#FirstEmail@Address.net=#Secondemail@addreess.net}.

It seems to retain the 1st email on all subsequent lines.  Equally if i do have a header, it retains this on each line and ass this to the username.

Sorry, this is most likely exceptionally simple, I just can't see the trees for the forest (or the code for the script!)

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you have an effective answer by now, but in the future please consider providing your questions in the form of an [mcve], or as close as you can get to one. Notably, that includes sample input and matching expected sample output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.  The first is that you are not importing the csv file correctly.  The second is that you are not referencing the resulting objects correctly.

First, it appears from your description that your csv file has no header.  This means that you are going to have to use the -header feature to provide your own header.

Second,  when a csv file is imported, the result is an array of PSCustomObjects.  You need to extract the (only) field in this object in order to pass a string to remove-msouser.

Try this:

```
  $Accounts = Import-Csv C:\temp\Emails.csv -header 'Address'

  ForEach ($line in $Accounts){

  remove-msoluser -UserPrincipalName $line.Address -Force  

  }
```